# How to make a copy of every row and column in one table for every index of another table in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

There are two dataframes, one with an index and another with no index. I want to make a new dataframe with the indices of the first and the rows and columns of the other in such a way that there is a copy of every data in the second table for each index.

```
df_A <- data.frame("index" = c("id1","id2","id3")
                   , variable_a = c(1,2,3)
                   , variable_b = c("x","f","d"))

df_B <- data.frame(variable_x = c("4124","414","123")
                   , variable_y = c(12,22,13)
                   , variable_z = c("q","w","d"))
```

The result should be:

```
df_C <- data.frame("index" = c("id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id2","id3","id3","id3")
                   , variable_x = c("4124","414","123","4124","414","123","4124","414","123")
                   , variable_y = c(12,22,13,12,22,13,12,22,13)
                   , variable_z = c("q","w","d","q","w","d","q","w","d"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a full outer join and could be solved via

```
 merge(df_B, df_A$index)
```

Which yields

```
> merge(df_B, df_A$index)
  variable_x variable_y variable_z   y
1       4124         12          q id1
2        414         22          w id1
3        123         13          d id1
4       4124         12          q id2
5        414         22          w id2
6        123         13          d id2
7       4124         12          q id3
8        414         22          w id3
9        123         13          d id3
```

You could correct the order of the columns like this:

```
merge(df_B, df_A$index)[,c(4, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Obviously, a full join can be done in `dplyr` as well, if you prefer that:

```
dplyr::full_join(df_B, df_A, by = character())
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `tidyr::crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(df_A, df_B)

#----------
# A tibble: 9 x 6
  index variable_a variable_b variable_x variable_y variable_z
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>           <dbl> <chr>     
1 id1            1 x          123                13 d         
2 id1            1 x          4124               12 q         
3 id1            1 x          414                22 w         
4 id2            2 f          123                13 d         
5 id2            2 f          4124               12 q         
6 id2            2 f          414                22 w         
7 id3            3 d          123                13 d         
8 id3            3 d          4124               12 q         
9 id3            3 d          414                22 w
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function should help using the library dplyr. Insert the dataframe with index in the first parameter and add the dataframe without index in the second parameter. It should return the requested dataframe.

```
merge_lines_with_index <- function(index_table, data_table){
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(data_table) + 1))
  x <- names(data_table) %>% unlist()
  colnames(df) <- c("index", x)
  for (item in index_table %>% select(1) %>% unlist()) {
    new_data <- data_table %>%
      mutate("index" = item)
    df <- df %>% rbind(new_data)
  }
  return(df[-1,])
}
```